# What's the arithmetic behind dynamic memory allocation with multidimentional arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

Once I was writting an app I thought it can be convenient for me to use 3-dimentional dynamically allocated array because of indexing. However I couldn't use it because it took much more memory then I expected. Please someone explain me what's the arithmetic behind this. Why here in following example var2 takes approx. 640 MB of memory not 256 MB. Tested in Dev-C++ 5.11 64-bit

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    using namespace std ;

    MEMORYSTATUS memInfo ;
    memInfo.dwLength = sizeof(memInfo) ;

    unsigned char *var0 ;
    unsigned char **var1 ;
    unsigned char ***var2 ;

    GlobalMemoryStatus(&memInfo) ;
    cout << "Free memory:\t" << (memInfo.dwAvailPhys / 1024 / 1024) << " MB" << endl ;

    var0 = new unsigned char[1024 * 1024 * 256] ;
    for(int aa = 0; aa < 1024 * 1024 * 256; aa++)
    var0[aa] = 0x00 ;

    GlobalMemoryStatus(&memInfo) ;
    cout << "Free memory:\t" << (memInfo.dwAvailPhys / 1024 / 1024) << " MB" << endl ;

    delete[] var0 ;

    cout << endl ;

    GlobalMemoryStatus(&memInfo) ;
    cout << "Free memory:\t" << (memInfo.dwAvailPhys / 1024 / 1024) << " MB" << endl ;

    var1 = new unsigned char*[128 * 1024] ;
    for(int aa = 0; aa < 128 * 1024; aa++)
    var1[aa] = new unsigned char[1024] ;

    for(int aa = 0; aa < 128 * 1024; aa++)
    for(int bb = 0; bb < 1024; bb++)
    var1[aa][bb] = 0x00 ;

    GlobalMemoryStatus(&memInfo) ;
    cout << "Free memory:\t" << (memInfo.dwAvailPhys / 1024 / 1024) << " MB" << endl ;

    delete[] var1 ;

    cout << endl ;

    GlobalMemoryStatus(&memInfo) ;
    cout << "Free memory:\t" << (memInfo.dwAvailPhys / 1024 / 1024) << " MB" << endl ;

    var2 = new unsigned char**[16 * 1024] ;
    for(int aa = 0; aa < 16 * 1024; aa++)
    var2[aa] = new unsigned char*[1024] ;
    for(int aa = 0; aa < 16 * 1024; aa++)
    for(int bb = 0; bb < 1024; bb++)
    var2[aa][bb] = new unsigned char[16] ;

    for(int aa = 0; aa < 16 * 1024; aa++)
    for(int bb = 0; bb < 1024; bb++)
    for(int cc = 0; cc < 16; cc++)
    var2[aa][bb][cc] = 0x00 ;

    GlobalMemoryStatus(&memInfo) ;
    cout << "Free memory:\t" << (memInfo.dwAvailPhys / 1024 / 1024) << " MB" << endl ;

    // Why does var2 takes approx. 640 MB of memory ?. 16 *1024 * 1024 * 16 = 256 MB

    cout << "\nPress a key to exit." << endl ;
    getch() ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this matters - I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues, one is memory manager overhead. You are allocating a large number of small blocks. The other is the size of the pointers.

var2 = new unsigned char**[16 * 1024] ;

This allocates a block of memory big enough to store 16x1024 pointers. You say you are using a 64 bit compiler so each pointer is 8 bytes. So this allocates a 128 kilobyte block. This is negligable and we won't consider it further.

for(int aa = 0; aa < 16 * 1024; aa++)
    var2[aa] = new unsigned char*[1024] ;

This allocates 16384 blocks each big enough to hold 1024 pointers. So each block is 8 kilobytes in size. A total of 128 megabytes.

for(int aa = 0; aa < 16 * 1024; aa++)
    for(int bb = 0; bb < 1024; bb++)
    var2[aa][bb] = new unsigned char[16] ;

This allocates 16777216 blocks each 16 bytes in size. A total of 256 megabytes.

So if the memory manager had zero overhead you would have allocated about 384 megabytes. So we have 256 megabytes still to account for.

When the memory manager allocates a block there is some overhead to store metadata about the allocation. Exactly how much depends on the implementation of the memory manager. In your case it looks like the memory manager has 16 bytes (the equivilent of 2 pointers) of overhead per allocation.

So now we know what the problems are what can we do about them?

We can eliminate most of the memory manager overhead by allocating memory in bigger blocks and doing some pointer arithmetic.

```
size_t dim1 = 16 * 1024;
size_t dim2 = 1024;
size_t dim3 = 16;
var2 = new unsigned char**[dim1] ;
unsigned char ** tmpa = new unsigned char*[dim1*dim2] ;
for(int aa = 0; aa < dim1; aa++) {
  var2[aa] = tmpa;
  tmpa += dim2;
}
unsigned char * tmpb = new unsigned char[dim1*dim2*dim3];
for(int aa = 0; aa < dim1; aa++) {
  for(int bb = 0; bb < 1024; bb++) {
    var2[aa][bb] = tmpb;
    tmpb += dim3;
  }
}
```

Reduing the overhead from the pointers is tricker. One option if you have some idea in advance of the relative sizes of the dimentions may be to reshape your array design so that the last dimension is not so small.

Comment: OK. I'd like to know how to calculate size of this overhed. Just curious

Comment: Looks like you just calculated it.

Comment: Anyway it's not just overhead from the memory manager.... you are forgetting to factor in the size of all those pointers!!

Comment: I don't know. If I couldn't check with function call I couldn't know how to calculate by my own. I think that sometimes it is a requirement to know how much memory will be used

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for

Comment: @Daro: Then use your first solution, in which all but a few extra bytes comes directly from your data. I don't know why you'd do it the nested-pointers way.